# How to validate passed arguments, values and dependencies between arguments?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I am very much new to shell script and I am writing a script takes some arguments from the user. The description of these arguments is given in the HELP section. I want to validate these arguments passed by the user so that he doesn't pass wrong arguments. Some of the arguments need to be in certain format like datetime for instance. -

```
    #!/bin/bash
    set -u
    set -o pipefail

    exit_status=0
    FRUIT=fruit
    CERT_PATH=cert
    KEY_PATH=key
    USERNAME=username
    DATETIME=datetime

    die() {
        printf '%s\n' "$1" >&2
        exit 1
    }

    show_help() {
        cat << EOF


        HELP:
        ==========================================================================================================================

        Description:

            --fruit or -f:          fruit name: mango, strawberry, grapes, apple, kiwiXX
            --cert or -c            cert
            --key or -k             key
            --username or -un       username to be passed when fruit is apple
            --datetime or -dt       datetime format: 2018-11-07 10:02:01

            --help or -h:           help for <cmd>

        ==========================================================================================================================

    EOF
        exit "$exit_status"
    }

        set_arguments () {
            while [ $# != 0 ]; do

                 case "${1:-}" in
                      -h|-\?|--help)
                          show_help    # Display a usage synopsis.
                          exit
                          ;;
                      -f|--fruit)
                          FRUIT="${2:-}"
                          shift
                          ;;
                      -c|--cert)
                          CERT_PATH="${2:-}"
                          shift
                          ;;
                      -k|--key)
                          KEY_PATH="${2:-}"
                          shift
                          ;;
                      -un|--username)
                          USERNAME="${2:-}"
                          shift
                          ;;
                      -dt|--datetime)
                          DATETIME="${2:-}"
                          fi
                          shift
                          ;;
                      -?*)
                          show_help
                          exit 1
                          ;;
                        *)
                          die 'ERROR: unknown argument.'
                          ;;
                 esac
                 shift
            done
}

# get the incoming arguments and set the variables.
set_arguments "$@"
```

The argument --fruit cannot be anything other than `mango, strawberry, grapes, apple, or kiwi-qx-XX`. If it is `kiwi`, it must contain `-qx- and a number`. For eg: `kiwi-qx-01` or `kiwi-qx-02` or `kiwi-qx-100`. If the fruit is an apple, the user must pass the argument username. If it is not an apple then the user must not pass a username. The date-time should have a specific format as shown in the HELP section. How to validate these passed arguments? What is the best way to do that?

Comment: sems to call for nested case statements to me ...

Comment: Why not use `getopts`?

Comment: @Inian, ...how does getopts help with the validation logic (ie. asserting that an argument is passed only when semantically valid)?

Answer (score 1):

I know it is not strictly speaking a validation but you could simply do the following for specific input of parameters:

```
case "$1" in
      valueneeded)
      #do something
      ;;

      *)
        clear
        explain what the accepted input is
        exit 1
esac
```

As for values:

It would depend on the value in question. For example:
In order to check if the value is an url:

```
regexdom='(https?|http|)://[-A-Za-z0-9\+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Za-z0-9\+&@#/%=~_|]'
if ! [[ $1 =~ $regexdom ]]
then
    echo "Url introduced is invalid exiting srcipt..."
    exit 1
fi
```

Substitute the regexdom by a regex you need to complete. 
You can use https://regex101.com/ to field test the regex prior implementation in a script.

In addition, seeing the amount of possible arguments maybe it would be best to consider switching to getopts:

```
while getopts ":a" opt; do
  case $opt in
    a)
      echo "-a was triggered!" >&2
      ;;
    \?)
      echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
      ;;
  esac
done
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I will give You little start:

- study [getopts](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html)
- validate using regexps

Here is small example only for arguments fruit -f and datatime -d:

```
#!/bin/bash
while getopts f:d: arg
do
  case ${arg} in
    f)
      if [[ "${OPTARG}" =~ "^apple$|^mango$|^kiwi-qx-[0-9]+$" ]]
      then
        echo "fruit OK"
      else
        echo "fruit KO"
      fi
      ;;
    d)
      if [[ "${OPTARG}" =~ "^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}$" ]]
      then
        echo "datetime OK"
      else
        echo "datetime KO"
      fi
      ;;
  esac
done
exit 0
```

Note: I simplified task only for three fruits and datatime regexp can also be more stricter.

Also notice that short arguments can be only one character that's why -d.

Test:

```
$ ./args.sh -f kiwi-qx-100 -d "2018-11-07 10:02:01"
fruit OK
datetime OK

$ ./args.sh -f pear -d "2018-07 10:02"
fruit KO
datetime KO
```

Comment: The right-hand side of `=~` can't be quoted, or it's treated as a literal substring to match against instead of a regex. (That is to say, `[[ $str =~ $regex ]]` checks for whether the string in the variable `str` matches the regex in the variable `regex`, but `[[ $str =~ "$regex" ]]` checks whether the variable `str` *contains the contents of the variable `regex` as literal text*).

Comment: Thanks. But how than is handled regex with space inside for example. It must be always passed in variable? How come that above works?

Comment: You can quote only part of a string: `[[ $str =~ foo" "bar ]]`. But yes, always passing a regex in a variable in bash *is* best practice; some of the first versions of bash to have `=~` syntax had inconsistent behavior in the literal case, whereas the pass-in-a-variable case always works the same way across all shell releases where the syntax exists at all.